# justification for 'population prediction intervals'?

Tags: confidence-interval, frequentist, profile-likelihood

Suppose we are living in a frequentist world and want to compute confidence intervals on some quantity that is a complicated function of the parameters $q_1 = f(\Theta)$ (i.e., there's no closed-form solution that would let us re-express this in terms of one of the parameters $\theta_j = g(\Theta_{-j}, q_1)$.

- The classical way to do this, AFAIK, would be to compute likelihood profile confidence intervals by computing $\max {\cal L}(\Theta)|q_1 = \hat {q_1}$  for a series of $\hat {q_1}$ around $f(\Theta_{\text{MLE}})$, then find the critical values of $\hat q_1$ such that the difference in the log-likelihood is half of the critical value of $\chi^2_1$ ([Wilks' theorem, blah blah blah](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389797/profile-likelihood-confidence-interval-proof)). **Problem**: we need an efficient, robust algorithm for equality-constrained nonlinear optimization (these do exist, e.g. using Lagrange multipliers, but are much less available/tested than those for unconstrained or box-constrained optimization).
- We could do parametric bootstrapping (sorry, no link). **Problem**: slow.
- We could assume that Wald statistics are OK and use the delta method to approximate the variances of the derived quantity (assuming that we can compute the Jacobian of $f(\Theta)$ by finite differences or automatic differentiation or ...). **Problem**: combines the assumption of "multivariate Normal sampling distribution"/"quadratic log-likelihood surface" with "$f$ has constant curvature".

A shortcut  that I've seen used, and used myself, is to assume (approximate) multivariate Normality of the sampling distribution of the parameters; draw a MVN sample (based on the observed information matrix); compute $f(\Theta)$ for each sample; and find the quantiles of the computed values.

Lande et al (2003) call these "population prediction intervals". Bolker (2008) says that a problem with this approach is that:

> It blurs the line between frequentist and Bayesian approaches. Several
> papers (including some of mine, e.g. Vonesh and Bolker (2005)) have used this approach, but I have yet to see a solidly grounded justification for propagating the sampling distributions of the parameters in this way.

Is anyone aware of such a justification, or is this really just cheesy pseudo-Bayesianism?

(Alternatively, are there elegant ways of computing well-justified confidence intervals on complex (not-easily-invertible) functions of parameters?)

---

Lande, R., S. Engen, and B.-E. Sæther. 2003. *Stochastic Population Dynamics in Ecology and Conservation*. Oxford University Press, Oxford, UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the econometrics literature this is referred to as the method of Krinsky and Robb ([1986](https://doi.org/10.2307/1924536), [1990](https://doi.org/10.2307/2109761), & [1991)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01193491).

I think the argument goes as follows:
Assume we have consistently estimated the expectation and the covariance matrix of an asymptotically normal estimator $\hat{\Theta}$ of $\Theta$. Then, by the law of large numbers, we can estimate the expectation, variance, and quantiles of the distribution of $f(\hat{\Theta})$ by drawing a random sample $\left\{\tilde{\Theta}^{(1)},\ldots,\tilde{\Theta}^{(M)}\right\}$ of size $M$ (where $M$ is large) from the asymptotic normal distribution of $\hat{\Theta}$ and using the sample mean/variance/quantiles of $\left\{f\left(\tilde{\Theta}^{(1)}\right),\ldots,f\left(\tilde{\Theta}^{(M)}\right)\right\}$ as consistent estimates for their population counterparts.

From the simulation studies I've read about this method I remember that it was, overall, not superior to the delta method.

Comment: Can you add references to some of this simulation studies?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Besides Krinsky and Robb ([1990](https://doi.org/10.2307/2109761), [1991](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01193491)) I recall Hole ([2006](https://doi.org/10.1002/hec.1197)) off the top of my head. In any case, which one performs better depends on the function of interest $f$ and the data at hand.