Efficient methods for generating error bars on likelihood estimates
Suppose I have some likelihood function that I’ve maximized to get the most likely parameters to have generated some experimental data. I now want error bars on those quantities. What are my options?
One option I can imagine is looking at the Hessian of the likelihood near the maximum, giving a covariance matrix where I’ve supposed the likelihood distribution is Gaussian. This might be ok, but seems to assume too much.
Another option is sampling the likelihood function with MCMC methods, and then analyzing the samples to get confidence intervals. This is fairly rigorous, but computationally very expensive when the likelihood function is expensive to evaluate.
What are some other options that might give trustworthy error bars/confidence intervals where my likelihood function is expensive to evaluate?

Profile likelihood, for one example see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315703/confidence-interval-on-the-percentage-difference-of-two-binomial-distributions/401884#401884

You could bootstrap the confidence intervals, but that would be as computationally demanding (if not more) than straight-up MCMC sampling from the posterior.

In general there're multiple approaches other than Hessian of an assumed Gaussian and brute force MCMC, such as profile likelihood, approximate Bayesian computation (ABC), delta method deriving an asymptotic distribution, etc. In your specific situation where you have tractable but expensive likelihood function to infer point estimate of parameters, your Hessian method could be just fine since MLE is an asymptotically consistent estimator of a limiting normal distribution with i.i.d. data. Also frequentist bootstrapping and Bayesian variational inference might be straightforward and efficient as well.

Bootstrapping... uses random sampling with replacement (e.g. mimicking the sampling process), and falls under the broader class of resampling methods. Bootstrapping assigns measures of accuracy (bias, variance, confidence intervals, prediction error, etc.) to sample estimates. This technique allows estimation of the sampling distribution of almost any statistic using random sampling methods. Bootstrapping estimates the properties of an estimand by measuring those properties when sampling from an approximating distribution...  In the case where a set of observations can be assumed to be from an independent and identically distributed population, this can be implemented by constructing a number of resamples with replacement, of the observed data set.

Frequentist bootstrapping is simple, parallelizable and applicable to even small datasets compared to the full Bayesian MCMC inference.
If you still prefer Bayesian inference then variational inference (VI) may be more efficient than MCMC to approximate the parameters posterior by optimizing over a family of simple distributions such as multi-variate Gaussian. VI transforms the inference via sampling problem into an optimization problem which is usually more efficient.

For frequentist bootstrapping of a maximum likelihood analysis, I generate the datasets and then maximize the likelihood for each dataset, right? This doesn't seem terribly efficient.

It's possibly inefficient depending on your data size and MLE expense once you lose conjugate prior. If your data sample size is large, you can try subsampling technique often used in ML to reduce sample size when bootstrapping. Also you can do some rough sensitivity analysis to to arrive at a smaller number of bootstrap samples and use parallel computing libraries of your programming language while MCMC is sequential in nature with burn-in period to reach stationary distribution limiting parallelization.  So MCMC algos are more expensive.

HMC is better for high-dimensional posterior than MHMC  but it needs gradient of log-likelihood and log-prior. Frequentist profile likelihood is good when your parameters are not many with a differentiable likelihood function, but during intensive optimizations it often has local maxima problem to infer incorrect confidence level while bootstrapping doesn't have local maxima problem due to many bootstrapped samples. Since you didn't specify your dataset and parameters profile, you need to weigh each option. Hope my general answer helps!

so for what it's worth I do have a differentiable log-likelihood. I put a lot of work in to implement everything in JAX assuming everything would be a bit more performant than it is. Just looking for alternative technique given what I have.

Also I would say that for my case, the sample size is very small.

If your sample size is very small then I still prefer bootstrapping using paralell computing for each bootstrapped sample to derive their respective MLE intuitively. Hope my answer at least is helpful for your understanding. After you experimentation comparison with possibly MCMC algos, maybe you can report back for your empirical findings for your case. Good luck.
